# Check file extension with PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering how to make PHP to check what extension it have, and then execute a code. For example, lets see it's a .mp3 file then it would execute: echo 'This is a mp3 file.'; Of course not with that code of course - but more advanced.
Anyhow, got any ideas etc?

Comment: Do you really want filename extension?  Or content type?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [pathinfo() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to isolate the extension of the file and then use that value in an if statement.

Comment: Will this work if the file is uploading? Since there is no extension on the upload files (mine generally look like this tmp_name => /tmp/php8Nxotq).

Comment: Thanks. Almost have it now.
How can I do so pathinfo (PHP) will check a dir?

Comment: `echo "{mp3:\"music/$file_name\",ogg:\"musicogg/$path_parts\".ogg}";`
Where $file_name is looking into music dir (and working perfectly as it should), now I want the name it got from the music dir, and put on a .ogg extension to the last part of the code. Or where it would look into the musicogg dir and check if the files there. Kinda lost.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.  If all you are doing is checking for mp3, just explode on the period, pop the last one and then see if the string equal.

for example:

```
$name = "song.mp3";
$parts = explode('.', $name);
$extension = array_pop($parts);
if( $extension == 'mp3'){
    echo 'This is a mp3 file.';
}
```

If you are checking for a wide variety of extensions and they are uploaded use

```
$_FILES['file']['type'];
```

Comment: this will not work when the file name contains a dot. like for this file name it will fail "my.test.txt"

Comment: Yes it will cause you array_pop which removes the last element which is the extension.  I tried it and it worked, but give it a try and let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check this two options to do it:

```
$filename = 'music.mp3'
$ext = substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1);
```

or

```
$filename = 'music.mp3';
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filetype()` or `$_FILES[$file][type]` to get the file type
.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $file_name = "test.txt";
    $extension = pathinfo($file_name);
    echo "Your file extension is ".$extension ['extension'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to properly detect a file's type, use [Fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php).

Example ripped for PHP's comments:

```
<?php
$fi = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME,'/usr/share/file/magic');
$mime_type = $fi->buffer(file_get_contents($file));
```